# SVG: apply class to text in group?

Tags: svg

How do I apply a class to an SVG text element using a group?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" 
 font-family="arial" font-size="12pt" width="600">
  
<style>
  text.ginormous  { font-size:48pt }
</style>

<g style="class:ginormous"> 
  <text x="50" y="50" >no dice</text>
</g>
  
<text class="ginormous" x="50" y="120" >this works</text>


</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS in SVG works by the same rules as in HTML, so change to

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" 
 font-family="arial" font-size="12pt" width="600">

<style>
  text.ginormous,
  .ginormous text  { 
    font-size:48pt 
  }
</style>

<g class="ginormous"> 
  <text x="50" y="50" >no dice</text>
</g>

<text class="ginormous" x="50" y="120" >this works</text>


</svg>
```